# Find the certain text in the line and then return that line in C#

Tags: c#, readline

I have a big file and for the simplicity I am just showing a small part of it. The data looks like following:

```
NPSER   NASER   NQSER
10  5   3
TSSR    MPSER   JDNSR
15  10  6
```

What I need to do is to find for example NPSER and NASER and then assign the values NPSER as 10, NASER as 5 and NQSER as 3. For this small data set I could do as following:

```
    TextReader infile = new StreamReader(fileName);
    string line;
    int NPSER, NASER, NQSER;
     line = infile.ReadLine();

    string[] words = line.Split('\t');

    NPSER = Convert.ToInt32(words[0]);
    NASER = Convert.ToInt32(words[1]);
    NQSER = Convert.ToInt32(words[2]);
    infile.Close();
```

Instead of reading each line and assigning values, I want to write a function which will automatically fetch the line when I search upto three words in a line which would be easier and efficient for longer application.

I would appreciate other methods as well.

Comment: Are the keys unique to the file or only the line?

Comment: As an alternative if you have a linux operating system I'd recommend you to use nawk/awk command to read a large text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier if you can use LINQ:

```
var line = File.ReadLines("path")
     .SkipWhile(line => !line.Contains("NPSER")) // change this condition to suit your needs
     .Skip(1)
     .First();

var values = line.Split(new[] { ' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             .Select(int.Parse) 
             .ToArray();

int NPSER = values[0];
int NASER = values[1];
int NQSER = values[2];
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It is not quite what I want but I will ask another question as accept your answer.